# Pycharm gives pip error while installing CV2, PIL and other libraries?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, python-3.6, python-3.7

I have been using `Pycharm` from a long time, I was using `python 3.7` and it was working fine for me.
Lately  I have shifted to Machine learning and I came to know I can't use `OpenCv` in python 3.7 so i uninstalled python 3.7 and install `python 3.6`
Now When I tried to import libraries like `PIL, cv2` It gave me an error that you are using version 9.0 of pip. Update it to install these packages.(I was able to use cv2 in python 3.7)
So I updated it using `pycharm` and now it has been updated to `version 18.1`(could be seen in the given picture)
[image]

Now when I try to install the packages again it still gives me this error.
[image]

I have checked my version of pip from cmd and pip is also updated here.
[image]

`Python` is installed in the location "C:\Users\Riyouk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36"
I checked pip version at that location and it still gives version 18.1
[image]

Anyone who encountered same problem or have knowledge about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cv2 doesn't exist as a package on PyPi.

Use:

> pip install opencv-python

As [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) says:

> Unofficial pre-built OpenCV packages for Python.

For [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), use:

> pip install Pillow

Now you can import installed packages and use them:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
```